# react-query useMutation onerror

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

In my api function, I'm returning success => false, error=>error_1
I'm using useMutation to validate some data

```
export const validateSomeData = async (code, data, res) => {
    try{
        const response = await axios.post(`test/data/${code}`, {data});
        if(response.data.success){
            return response.data.coupon;
        }
        // add code here
    }catch(e){
        // and here
    }
};
```

I want to return error so that react query error and isError will be true
I tried to

```
throw new Error(response.data.error);
```

but error was filled with error_1 in test/data and the whole error stack I'm only interested in error_1
for context here is my useMutation hook

```
export const useDataValidation = () => {
    const { data, error, isError, isPending, mutateAsync } = useMutation({
        mutationKey: ["test"],
        mutationFn: (code, data) => validateSomeData (code, data),
    });
    return { data: data ?? {}, isPending, error, isError, validateData: mutateAsync}
};
```